# How can I set an array use foreach?

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
$arr = [
  
    [step_1] => Array
        (
            [method] => getLastRealisesData
            [description] => Get last realises data
            [error] => null
            [done] => 0
        )

    [step_2] => Array
        (
            [method] => downloadFile
            [description] => Download file
            [error] => null
            [done] => 0
        )

];

foreach($arr as $item){
   $result = 0;
   if($result == 0){
      $item['done'] = 0;
      $item['error'] = 'Error message';
      break;
   }

   $result = 1;
}
```

My value did not update, why?
I need to update my value if I my result == 0
Mayby I need to use object or somethink else...

Comment: `arr` is a variable so it would be `foreach ($arr ....`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to amend the array you are processing with the foreach loop, you have to use a reference, otherwise the foreach gets a copy of the array to process and any changes made within the loop to the array will dissapear at the end of the foreach as the copy is discarded.

```
foreach($arr as &$item){
//  note        ^ reference
    $result = 0;
    if($result == 0){
        $item['done'] = 0;
        $item['error'] = 'Error message';
        break;
    }
    $result = 1;
}
unset($item);  // unset the reference
```

Comment: Note that there is a surprising side-effect when using this approach: after the loop finishes, the `$item` variable *remains a reference to the last item it was set to*, so assigning a new value to it overwrites that item in the array (and vice-versa: assigning to that item in the array overwrites the local variable, but that's probably less likely to happen by accident). It's a good habit to add `unset($item);` after the loop to avoid this causing confusion.

Comment: I didnt know that @IMSoP but noted. Cant say I have ever noticed that, probably because i would not normally reuse that variable, but useful to know anyway

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah, it mostly comes up when you have such a loop in the middle of some long unstructured code, and later happen to want a variable with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

From php documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

```php
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
// $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)
unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
?>
```

Also you may be interested in what `by reference` means. Again, [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

**Note** also that reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

Comment: And what was the point of posting this